# How to install ant package in java correctly?

Tags: java, ant, weka, j48

jdk version: 17

I'm trying to use j48 in [weka](https://github.com/alibaba/mdrill/blob/master/trunk/adhoc-internal/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.java) for study it, but I got two problems.

First, I run the Run.java, and the complier throw a error: complier can not find java_cup package. So I follow this [tutor](https://www.skenz.it/compilers/install_windows) to install java_cup package, it's successful.

Second, CPUTask.java in java_cup package have another problem: complier can not find org.apache.tools.ant package. So I follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eaW81yYIqY) to install it. about 5:40 in video, I type "ant -version" in terminal, and show a sentence like a error.

Sorry about that it is Chinese. in English, it said: "must not have Files\FLC_Tools\java_cup_draw_tree now." but it is the package I have to install.

How should I fix this problem? I have to install java_cup and ant package both.

[image]

This is error line in CPUTask.java
[image]

Comment: You can find Ant here: https://ant.apache.org/

Comment: @Jesper yes, the video is also download ant from this website.

Comment: I suspect that the problem might be because you are working in `C:\Program Files`, a path with a space in it. Probably the project's build file cannot handle this. Try putting your project in a directory that does not have a space in the path. For example into `C:\Project\FLC_Tools\...`

Comment: @Jesper it really work! But the import package line in CPUTask.java still can not catch the ant package, what do I should do anything else?

Comment: I can import ant package! put org.apache.tools.ant-1.6.5.jar in jdk/lib. But package problem are coming one by one...so many package I have to install manually, everyone have to do this like me?